# How was Davy Jones able to talk to Tia Dalma (Calypso) if his ship hadn't arrived yet?

Tags: plot-explanation, pirates-of-the-caribbean, at-worlds-end

In *Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End*, there is a scene where Tia Dalma (Calypso) is in the brig aboard the Black Pearl, which is docked at Shipwreck Cove, and she is talking to Davy Jones. However later when the pirates undock from Shipwreck Cove we see Lord Beckett's armada, headed by the Endeavor and the Flying Dutchman, approaching the cove with Davy Jones at the helm of the Flying Dutchman.

So, how could Davy Jones have gotten into the Black Pearl to talk to Calypso if he was simultaneously miles away on the Flying Dutchman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Likely using teleportation

Davy Jones seems to have the ability to easily move through space,  even into solid objects as shown in several instances in *Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End*, in particular during his talk with Calypso when he walks into her closed cell.

In addition, in *Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man's Chest*, Davy Jones instantly teleported himself and some of his crewmembers onto the Black Pearl to talk with Jack.

The limits (range in particular) of his powers are unclear, but we know from that scene that he can instantly move at least from his ship to the Black Pearl.

From the [fandom wiki](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Davy_Jones):

> His position as the captain of the Flying Dutchman and the Ferryman to the Underworld gave Jones his ability to switch between the worlds of the dead and the living. This power was most likely the reason for other supernatural traits of him, including the abilities to teleport himself and walk through solid objects.

Comment: I would second that. Now that I remember, didn't Will Turner teleport himself back, at the end of At World's End? Seems like those powers are given to the captain of the Flying Dutchman.

Comment: I think you are right. I would have to watch that scene again.